# Powershell Foreach overwrites the output in excel

Tags: excel, powershell, export-to-excel, import-from-excel

** Update i made it work i needed to put the entire foreach inside a variable and it works

Powershell Foreach overwrites the output in excel

I have a script need help fixing it , the excel output is giving me the last output and overwrite the outputs , in powershell it gives the correct and shows all of the output

```
Import-Module ImportExcel
$FolderPath = "\\clalit\dfs$\HomeFS\Ram Idan Scripts"
$Acl = Get-Acl -Path $FolderPath
$AccessRules = $Acl.Access  
    foreach ($Rule in $AccessRules) {
    try{
        $Username = ($Rule.IdentityReference.Tostring().split("\")[1])
        $Permissions = ($Rule.FileSystemRights.Tostring().split(",")[0])
        $Email = (Get-ADUser $Username -Properties mail).mail
        $all = Get-ADUser $Username -Properties DisplayName,SamAccountName,mail  
        
    
        if( $Permissions -match "Modify"){
           
            $all | Select DisplayName,SamAccountName,mail 
            
            
        }
             
          

        else{}
            
        
       
    }catch{$nul}
   
    
}
 
$all | Select DisplayName,SamAccountName,mail | Export-Excel "$FolderPath\tests.xlsx" -FreezeTopRow -AutoSize
```

Comment: For starers, `$Username = ($Rule.` uses uninitialised variable. Fix that, and reformat the code, there's a lot of excess whitespace.

Comment: updated right now

Comment: If I get what you are trying to accomplish, you want all the output that shows in the terminal? If so, you may need to have some type of array to add them into like $allOutput += $all and then export it to excel.

Comment: sorry for the question how do i exactly i am kinda new to powershell im learning on the job for fun

Answer (score 0):

I have roughly composed the concept I proposed and have yet to test it but hoped to guide you in your learning.

```
Import-Module ImportExcel
$FolderPath = "\\clalit\dfs$\HomeFS\Ram Idan Scripts"
$Acl = Get-Acl -Path $FolderPath
# This is the array of output where you will keep adding the results
$allOutput = @{}
$AccessRules = $Acl.Access  
foreach ($Rule in $AccessRules) {
try{
    $Username = ($Rule.IdentityReference.Tostring().split("\")[1])
    $Permissions = ($Rule.FileSystemRights.Tostring().split(",")[0])
    $Email = (Get-ADUser $Username -Properties mail).mail
    $all = Get-ADUser $Username -Properties DisplayName,SamAccountName,mail  

    if( $Permissions -match "Modify"){
       # Assuming this is the only output you want to export all the time,we place it into the array.
       $allOutput += $all
        
    }          

    else{}       
   
}catch{$nul}
}
# Then you will just have to export the array into the excel
$allOutput | Export-Excel "$FolderPath\tests.xlsx" -FreezeTopRow -AutoSize
```